# Find a cell containing text in a range and return the text in that cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a range of data where each row is in alphabetical order and I want to pull each cell in the row that contains "client" to another column. [image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169090/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=iferror( filter(A2:H2, search("client", A2:H2)) )
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [search()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154) and [iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're expected result is. You can try with this formula in the first cell of your new column. Adapt A2:H to your actual range:

```
=BYROW(A2:H,LAMBDA(each,IF(COUNTA(each)=0,"",TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(each),"((?i)client.+)")))))))
```

If it's not what you're looking for, please give some feedback